# MultyQuery is working in phpmyadmin, is not working in Mysqli, did work on an other server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I'm using Msqli to make a multiquery, the query works exactly like i want within phpmyadmin.

it do not work with mysqli anymore. The query did not change between servers.

The query below Was working in a previous LAMP installation but not in the current.

```
$SQLquery ='set @type = \'\';
set @num  = 1;
SELECT 
RA.`DATE` as DATES, 
RA.`ADDR` as ADDR,
RA.`QID` as QID, 
RT.`TAGS` as TAG,
Q.`id` AS QUID,
Q.`ADDR` AS QADDR, 
Q.`ORIGINALTEXT` AS QTEXTS, 
Q.`DATE` AS QDATES, 
cs.`id` AS CUID,
cs.`ADDR` AS CADDR, 
cs.`ORIGINALTEXT` AS CTEXTS, 
cs.`DATE` AS CDATES,
sol.`id` AS SUID, 
sol.`ORIGINALTEXT` AS STEXTS,
sol.`ADDR` AS SADDR, 
sol.`DATE` AS SDATES,
prj.`id` AS PUID,  
prj.`ORIGINALTEXT` AS PTEXTS, 
prj.`ADDR` AS PADDR,
prj.`DATE` AS PDATES, 
Max(Q.`DATE` ) AS Q, 
Max(cs.`DATE` ) AS C, 
Max(sol.`DATE` ) AS S, 
Max(prj.`DATE` ) AS P,
#@num as row_number 
@num:= if(@type = RA.`ADDR`, 1+@num, 1)  as v_number,
@type := RA.`ADDR` as dummy
FROM        (SELECT `id`,`TAGS`, `QID`    from `REL_TAG` ) AS RT 
 inner Join (SELECT `DATE`, `ADDR`, `QID` from `REL_ADDR` order by DATE) AS RA ON ( RT.`QID` = RA.`QID`) 
 Left outer Join (SELECT `id`,`DATE`, `ADDR`, `QID`, `ORIGINALTEXT` FROM `QUESTION`) AS Q ON ( RT.`QID` = Q.`QID`) and Q.`ADDR` = RA.`ADDR`
 Left outer Join (SELECT `id`,`DATE`, `ADDR`, `QID`, `ORIGINALTEXT` FROM `CASES` order by `CASES`.`DATE`) AS cs ON ( RT.`QID` = cs.`QID`) and cs.`ADDR` = RA.`ADDR` 
 Left outer Join (SELECT `id`,`DATE`, `ADDR`, `QID`, `ORIGINALTEXT` FROM `SOLUTION` order by `SOLUTION`.`DATE`) AS sol ON ( RT.`QID` = sol.`QID`) and sol.`ADDR` = RA.`ADDR`
 Left outer Join (SELECT `id`,`DATE`, `ADDR`, `QID`, `ORIGINALTEXT` FROM `PROJECT`  order by `PROJECT`.`DATE`) AS prj ON ( RT.`QID` = prj.`QID`) and prj.`ADDR` = RA.`ADDR`
where RT.`QID` = \''.NbOnly($Fetchmodifier).'\' Group by `QID`, addr, v_number LIMIT '.$Anstart.' ,'.$Ansnb.';';
```

**Update**
The query does not return any error in the logs, it just return nothing (null).

Here is the PHP code to execute the MySQLi Multiquery

```
$mysqlin = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
if (mysqli_error($mysqlin)) {
     outputdataXML(sprintf("Connect Problem : %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqlin)));
     exit();
}
if ($mysqlin->multi_query($SQLquery)) {
    do {
          if ($result = $mysqlin->store_result()) {
               while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                   if( $Foundrows = $row[0]){ //Maybe the problem is here ?
                     $Outputvalue[] = FormatFile($row);
                   }
               }
               $result->free();
          }
          if ($mysqlin->more_results()) {
          }
       } while ($mysqlin->more_results() && $mysqlin->next_result());
}
$mysqlin->close();
```

Comment: @Jon none, i enabled the mysql logs check for errors , it just show the query i sent , it return Nothing

Comment: I think there is some thing wrong in the where condition where it is not escaped properly on php end

Comment: @raheel shan in that case would'nt it give me an error ?

Comment: Is the conditional correct? Won't if( $Foundrows = $row[0]){ always return true? Also the last if clause seems to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Found the problem, Some but not all of the tables Were **EMPTY**, 
As in Without any records,

I added a dummy record To each tables, some tables had records but some were without,
and now even if the Query dont matchThe joins are Now still being Made properly.

I  Hope this help lots of ppl.

When your using MySQL **"Join"**, you need 1 record in **each** and **All** of your joined tables, no matter if it will ever be used ex: 0, 00-00-0000, Null , 0, empty

Only then, all the joinning Tables included in the query will work.